# LibGDX get fonts saved on desktop/android

Tags: libgdx

Hello I would like to know how I can use the fonts saved on an android device or on desktop.

Also how to get the default font used by the platform.

I have some basic knowlege about the file module but never tried to acces data from the device it self.

Comment: 2 seconds on google and.. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype

Comment: Thats not what I'm searching for.

Comment: yes it is, read about  [File Handling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling). And there's no such thing as default font by OS.